# Is One tap sign-in Oauth2 under the covers

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-identity

Can we repoint the One tap sign-in to another Oath2 identity provider and have it work?. The docs state so, but I've not seen any examples. Is it too new? When did it come into existence.

Answer (score 0):

The one-tap UI only works with Google right now, but that would be something interesting to explore in the future.